# Python code to quickly change Dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, performance, time

I have a knowledge graph in pandas dataframe format `KG` as follows.

**Input**

```
KG:
           pred     subj      obj
0   nationality     BART      USA
1  placeOfBirth     BART  NEWYORK
2     locatedIn  NEWYORK      USA
3     hasFather     BART   HOMMER
4   nationality   HOMMER      USA
5  placeOfBirth   HOMMER  NEWYORK
```

And I want to change `KG` to dictionary as follows.

**result**

```
{'BART': {'subj': [0, 1, 3], 'obj': []},
 'HOMMER': {'subj': [4, 5], 'obj': [3]},
 'NEWYORK': {'subj': [2], 'obj': [1, 5]},
 'USA': {'subj': [], 'obj': [0, 2, 4]}}
```

The key of the dictionary is the subj and obj values of the `KG`, and the value is sub-dictionary. Sub-dictionary has subj and obj as the key, `KG` index with subj as the key, and `KG` index with obj as the key as the value.

Here is my code below.

```
entity_list = sorted(set(KG.subj.values).union(set(KG.obj.values)))
KG_index = {}
for entity in entity_list:
    KG_index[entity] = {'subj' : KG[KG['subj'] == entity].index.tolist(),
                        'obj' : KG[KG['obj'] == entity].index.tolist()}
```

This code takes a very long time in a large `KG`. Is there a faster and more efficient way than this code?

Comment: Use a Pandas' groupby. You are iterating over the whole dataframe again and again so the algorithm is currently quadratic.